# Spring MockMvc Integration Test Change OffsetDateTime to BigDecimal

Tags: spring-boot, testing, jsonserializer, offsetdatetime

OffsetDateTime is changed to decimal value 1653372600.654878000 after getting a result from GET endpoint in spring integration test using mockMvc.

I can solve it by using  `@JsonSerialize( using = JavaOffsetDateTimeSerializer.class )` but I have to use this in every fields.

I would like to know when jackson transform it into bigdecimal value and how could I handle this unexpected data change in integration test